# How to handle private members of a base class when implementing copy control in C++?

Tags: c++, inheritance, copy-constructor, assignment-operator

Given a Teacher class that derives from a Faculty class, how would I handle the name of a Teacher object, which is defined as a private member in Faculty but not in Teacher, for copy control?

```
// example code for the two classes
class Faculty{
public:
/* constructor

   copy constructor

   destructor

   assignment operator
*/

string get_name() const{
return name;

private:
string name;
};

class Teacher : public Faculty{};
```

Assuming that Faculty class has a functioning copy control

```
// Copy constructor
Teacher(const Teacher& rhs) : Faculty(rhs){
     name = rhs.name; 
}
```

This line doesn't compile because it tries to access a private member of Faculty. Is this line needed or is the name of the copy already set to rhs.name by the initialization list, Faculty(rhs)? Would name be accessible if I directly define a string name in the private field of Teacher?

```
// Assignment operator
Teacher& operator=(const Teacher& rhs){
     Faculty::operator=(rhs);
     if(this != &rhs){
          name = rhs.name; // same issue 
     }
     return *this;
}
```

Same issue as copy control, is this needed or is the name already changed to rhs.name by the Faculty class's assignment operator?

Comment: This looks like a case for the Rule Of Zero. Just don't declare or define the copy constructor or assignment operator at all, and the right thing will happen.

Comment: Also, why would a `Teacher` derive from `Faculty`?    Public inheritence generally represents is-a relationships  (e.g.  a dog is a type of animal, so a `Dog` class would derive from `Animal`).  A `Teacher` is not a type of `Faculty`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is this line needed or is the name of the copy already set to rhs.name
> by the initialization list, Faculty(rhs)?

No the line is not needed (assuming a default or properly implemented `Faculty` copy constructor). The `Faculty` constructor will assign or initialise `name` for you properly.

> Would name be accessible if I directly define a string name in the
> private field of Teacher?

Yes, kind of. But it will be an entirely separate instance of `name`. You don't want to do this. You only want `name` defined once.

Comment: A follow up question if you don't mind, would my Teacher constructor take in name as a parameter or not since it can't access it? Would it be 1. Teacher(string name) : Faculty(name) {} or 2. Teacher() : Faculty(name) {}? Thank you.

Comment: Yes teacher can accept name in its constructor and pass it to base class. So 1 is correct.